# What information should be included in comments at the top of a file?

Tags: python, comments

I'm writing a small Python program for my company that only a few managers are going to be using. What should typically be included in the comments at the top of files?

I've included the date of creation and last edit in the main file, but is it common include my name as well in the comments?